# Частичная перерисовка canvas в android

Tags: java, android, canvas

Подскажите, каким способом можно сделать частичную перерисовку canvas. При вызове метода invalidate() будет перерисован весь холст, а как сделать именно дорисовку к существующему?

Мне нужно на нарисованной гексагональной сетке перекрасить некоторые шестиугольники, и не хотелось бы для этого заново рисовать всю сетку.

```
 for (Hexagon hexagon: hexagonalGrid.getHexagons()) 
   drawPoly(canvas, convertToPointsArr(hexagon.getPoints(), array), "#FF5346", Style.STROKE);
```

```
 private void drawPoly(Canvas canvas, int[] array, String color, Style style)          {

   Paint p = new Paint();

   p.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
   p.setStyle(style);

   if (width > 15) p.setStrokeWidth(2);
   else if (width > 30) p.setStrokeWidth(1);
   else p.setStrokeWidth(5);

   Path polyPath = new Path();
   polyPath.moveTo(array[0], array[1]);

   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i = i + 2)
     polyPath.lineTo(array[i], array[i + 1]);

   polyPath.lineTo(array[0], array[1]);
   canvas.drawPath(polyPath, p);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Да, можно. Вы можете вычислить прямоугольный регион, который необходимо перерисовать, и передать его в метод [`public void invalidate(Rect dirty)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate(android.graphics.Rect))

Comment: Всё не так просто. Само по себе это не спасёт, это поставит на перерисовку (полную!) все вьюхи, попадающие в регион. Чтобы делать частичную перерисовку, ему нужно как минимум где-то получить описывающий прямоугольник перерисовываемой области и подстроить отрисовку под него.